# parcel did not inject js and css code to the resulted html

Tags: html, npm, web-applications, build, parceljs

I am new to Parcel and to web dev in general.

I am watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf9ExEkySjo) to learn about parcel.
In this video he uses, what I understand now, parcel v1.
When I tried to install it (`package: parcel-bundler`) I got huge list of  warnings and errors, from which I have learned that parcel v2 is now available, and better to use, under the `package name: parcel` so I:

`npm uninstall parcel-bundler`

and then

`npm install --save-dev -g parcel`.

**building the project**

installed parcel number: `parcel --version 2.4.0`

My sample project is simple:
`index.html` with script and css files.

`<script src="js/main.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/main.scss">`

After building the project with

```
parcel build client/index.html --no-optimize --no-cache
```

I expected the output html to include the code within the js,css files.
But the result was that it looks like it only renamed the js,css files, and didn't inject the code to the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.ef1c6e2b.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="idh1">main header</h1>
    <script src="/index.a61d77df.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the package.json is

```
{
  "name": "webappsetup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/google-apps-script": "^1.0.45",
    "parcel-plugin-inliner": "^1.0.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

My question is, am I right to expect the dist/index.html include the js and css code, as in the video (which is using `parcel-bundler`), or `parcel` works differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why the output `dist/index.html` that parcel builds merely *references* the output css file (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.ef1c6e2b.css">`) and the output js file (`<script src="/index.a61d77df.js"></script>`), rather than inlining the contents. Is that right? I'm assuming the app will run correctly, but please post additional details if that's not the case.

So, assuming I got that right, this is expected behavior probably desirable for most use cases.

If for some reason your use case requires that you have inline scripts and styles, you could do it like this (see [docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/html/#inline-scripts-and-styles)):

```
<style>
   @import "./style.scss";
 </style>
 <script type="module">
   import value from "./other.ts";
   console.log(value);
 </script>
```

But, as the docs recommend...

> Note: Use this sparingly, as big inline scripts/styles can be detrimental to the (perceived) load speed.

Comment: you got that tight. I do not really need one big html containing all css and js file(s). This is what the video presented and I didn't understand why I do not get the same behavior. But if what I get is actually the expected results, this is good enough for me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added script commands to your package.json file. Delete test in scripts and add --public-url ./ to your build command.
Like this;

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/*.html --open",
    "build": "parcel build client/index.html --no-optimize --no-cache --public-url ./"
  },
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. I ran the `build` from the command line, not by running the build command in the `package.json` (which I do not know yet, how to use). Anyway, I added the `--public-url ./` and run it again from command line, got the same results. I also modified the `package.json` as suggested and run again same way, didn't help. Still got the same resulted html file